# Conditional expectation of symmetric statistic has the same distribution when conditioning on iid random variables

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose I have iid random variables $\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ and a statistic $S(X_1,...,X_n)$ that is symmetric (i.e. if $ (\sigma_{i})_{i=1}^n $ is a permutation of $\{1,...,n \} $, then $S(x_1,...,x_n) = S(x_{\sigma_1},...,x_{\sigma_n} )$).

$\textbf{How do I show that $\mathbb{E}(S(X_1,...,X_n)|X_i) \overset{d}{=} \mathbb{E}(S(X_1,...,X_n)|X_j)?$}$, i.e. the conditional expectations have the same distribution?

Related link: [Conditional expectation of iid random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308816/conditional-expectation-of-iid-random-variables)

$\textbf{motivation:}$ Efron and Stein (1981) used this "identity" https://pdodds.w3.uvm.edu/research/papers/others/1981/efron1981a.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be independent identically distributed real valued random variables. Then for any admissible $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $E[g(X)]=E[g(Y)]$ by identical distribution, and for any admissible $h:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ also have [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768648/a-question-about-conditional-expectations?noredirect=1). So (we talk about a.s. equalities when dealing with conditional expectations)
$$\begin{aligned}E[f(X,Y)|X]&=E[f(x,Y)]|_{x=X}\sim\\
&\sim E[f(y,Y)]|_{y=Y}=\\
&=E[f(y,X)]|_{y=Y}=\\
&=E[f(Y,X)|Y]\end{aligned}$$
We conclude by using the assumption $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$.

Comment: +1. Actually $\mathrm E[f(X_1,\dots,X_n) \mid X_i = x]$ does not depend on $i$ (modulo negligible sets), which is a bit stronger statement.

Comment: @Snoop thanks for your answer! Can I ask if this can be extended to $\mathbb{E}[f(X_1,…,X_n)|X_1,X_2] \overset{d}{=} \mathbb{E}[f(X_1,…,X_n)|X_1,X_3]?$

Comment: @dante you're welcome! You should post another question about that ;) (suggestion: link this one for context)

Comment: @Snoop I’ll do that. Thanks for the suggestion!